# WebClient, WebRequest and Stream not returning anything...?

Tags: c#, forms, web-scraping, pastebin

I have tried both WebClient's DownloadSring and WebRequest+Stream to try and scrape a page ([This one](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hT62cqQv)) and get the Raw Paste data from it. I have scoured the net but have found no answers.
I have this code:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=" +  textBox1.Text);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
string pasteContent = "";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
{
    pasteContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
new Note().txtMain.Text += pasteContent;
new Note().txtMain.Refresh();
```

and I have multiple forms so I am editing Note's `txtMain` textbox to add the paste content but it seems to return nothing, no matter which function I use. I know cross-form editing works because I have multiple things that can return to it.

How can I scrape the raw data?

Thank you VERY much,
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in downloading the content of your site. You simply doesn't use the instance of the `Node` class you created.

```
var note = new Note();

note.txtMain.Text += pasteContent;
note.Show();
```

Comment: That opens up an entirely new Note form... is there a way I can edit the existing Note form? it is already on the screen. thanks

Comment: Then use its instance instead of creating new one. I have no idea what Note class is, where you create it? where you keep a reference to it?

Comment: How? it says I need an object refrence. The 'Note' class is the main form of my notepad-ish program. it holds a textbox, status bar, menu bar, etc.

Comment: @Parzivail Create your Note class once and store its reference somewhere. Use that reference throughout your app.